# Google blogger api and expired secret key.

Tags: oauth, google-api

I have already managed to add some posts to my blog using google api and oauth and ran into some problems. I have tried for days - or weeks - to find the best question to ask and I believe I have isolated the problem. Apparently the secret key only works only for one hour. but after an hour at this line:

```
        $service->blogs->getByUrl("theurlofmyblog.blogspot.com");
```

I get this error:

```
Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:

{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
 {
 "domain": "global",
 "reason": "authError",
 "message": "Invalid Credentials",
 "locationType": "header",
 "location": "Authorization"
 }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
 }
```

Some of the experts on forums have suggested that one must go to this address https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and get a referesh token. But nobody has mentioned that how should we use that token. Do I put it inside the json file? There must be something like this - don't laugh please, this is supposed to be a suedo code -:

```
 if(the key is expired)
      use my referesh key and get me another key
```

Any experience?

Comment: The oauthplayground is an Google's Oauth2 testing environment there you can test your authorization flow. If the access token expires within an hour then you can get new one using the "refresh_token" if you have one. You can obtain it from the initial authorization response. If you don't have then you just have to authorize again to get new access token. What grant flow you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Google’s OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), you should receive a refresh token during the authentication flow. You should store that token someplace, then use it to get a new access token when necessary.

The exact procedure to exchange a refresh token for a new access token will depend on what OAuth client library you are using. In Signet (Google’s OAuth library for Ruby), for example, it’s done as part of [`fetch_access_token`](https://github.com/google/signet/blob/master/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb#L949).